# How To Determine What Class/Module a Method is in

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Coming from working with Java in Eclipse, it's always been extremely easy for me to determine where a method was defined: simply ctrl+click the method call and it brings you to the method definition in its containing class. Obviously it's Eclipse that makes a lot of this happen, but even with plain old Java, we still have the import statements to fall back on.

Method lookups seem to be very difficult with Rails development.

Here's an example:

```
require 'test_helper'

class UserStoriesTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest
  fixtures: products

  LineItem.delete_all
  Order.delete_all
  ruby_book = products(:ruby)

  get "/"
  assert_response :success
  assert_template "index"

  cart = Cart.find(session[:cart_id])
  assert_equal 1, cart.line_items.size
  assert_equal ruby_book, cart.line_items[0].product

  get "/orders/new"
  assert_response :success
  assert_template "new"
end
```

Let's say I wanted to take a closer look at the **assert_equal** method. If I was working with Java and the class that contained **assert_equal** would probably be described by an import statement in this class with its location explicitly specified (e.g. *java.lang.SomeCoreClass*). Since I have no idea where the hell this method is defined, what I end up doing is Googling for "assert_equal" to find that the method I'm investigating is (probably and hopefully) defined in **Test::Unit::Assertions**.

I'm interested to hear from a few people on their approaches to determining method locations.

Comment: Are you asking which editor supports ctrl-click for "go to definition" ? RubyMine does that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this:

```
class Bong
  def smoke
    puts "smoke"
  end
end

Bong.method(:smoke)
Bong.method(:smoke).source_location
```

Comment: lmao best SO answer ever. props.

Comment: a relevant example always helps ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `method(:<method_name>).owner` to track the class of the method. In your case it would be `method(:assert_equal).owner`.

[method#owner](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Method.html#method-i-owner)

Comment: yeah but how does that help me? i can't just fire up irb and type assert_equal.owner.

Comment: you can use it in the scope of your project to find out which class is defining your method. If you define your class in irb then you should be able to use this method in irb as well.

Comment: in your test case file just print p method(:assert_equal).owner.